# Execute function in order in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, function

I'm having this piece of code written in javascript

```
preDefineListName = ['Applied', 'Test taken', 'SWS Interview', 'Candidate', 'Rejected'];

for (var i = 0; i < preDefineListName.length; i++) {
      Trello.addList(data.id, preDefineListName[i]);
};

Trello.addList = function (trelloBoardId, listName) {
    return $http.post('https://api.trello.com/1/lists', {
        idBoard: trelloBoardId,
        name: listName,
        key: trelloKey,
        token: trelloToken
    });
};
```

now above function Trello.addList in the for loop makes a list on the trello.com  with the given names in preDefineListName. The problem is the lists are not appearing in the order as they passed.

What should I do to make it in proper order. and i've to call function in the loop so I can't change it.

Comment: Is the `Trello.addList()` method asynchronous? If so there's no way to guarantee the order the requests are returned in. You would need to hook an event to when all the requests are finished and then order the list.

Comment: What is `data` variable?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so is their any way that i can make Trello.addList() synchronous.

Comment: I don't know the Trello SDK, but unless they specifically have a method or option which is synchronous, then I doubt it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Trello.addList() is not from Trello SDK I've made this method.

Comment: Ah, then can you add the code for it to the question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan added the code please check

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. Trello is a object here

Comment: `$http.post` is async method, so one request can return faster than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Trello.addList` returns a [Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and is asynchronous (as it executes an http call). You therefore need an asynchronous loop instead of the `for` loop as well. This would be a `.forEach` call on the `preDefineListName` list.

You can however use `.map` as well, which lets you return the result of the `Trello.addList` calls and then use [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) to wait until all addList calls are done:

```
$q.all(preDefineListName.map(function(name) {
    return Trello.addList(data.id, name);
})).then(function success(results) {
    // do something with the results
}, function error(reasons) {
    // handle errors here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use promises and recursion. Looks a bit hacky, but will make things synchronous:

```
preDefineListName = ['Applied', 'Test taken', 'SWS Interview', 'Candidate', 'Rejected'];

Trello.addList(data.id, preDefinedListName); // Initiate list adding

Trello.addList = function(trelloBoardId, listNames) {
   if(!listNames.length) {
      return;
   }

   var listName = listNames[0];
   listNames.splice(0, 1); // Remove first element from array

   $http.post('https://api.trello.com/1/lists', {
        idBoard: trelloBoardId,
        name: listName,
        key: trelloKey,
        token: trelloToken
   }).then(function(response) {
       Trello.addList(trelloBoardId, listNames); // Call the function again after this request has finished.
   });
}
```